# Google Chat App - Script repeats twice on android devices

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-chat

In a Google Chat application developed with Apps Script, when using the **standalone chat app** on an Android device, if the chat throws the error '...is unable to process your request' upon clicking a button within a card (due to script execution taking more than 5 seconds), the script associated with the action of the button repeats twice.

I provide an example of my code and the onMessage functions (which create the card with a button) and onClickCard.

```
function onCardClick(event) {
  Utilities.sleep(5000)
  console.log("Clicked")
}

function onMessage(event) {
  return {
    "cardsV2": [
      {
        "cardId": "TestPoker",
        "card": {
          "sections": [
            {
              "widgets": [
                {
                  "buttonList": {
                    "buttons": [
                      {
                        "text": "Test Button",
                        "onClick": {
                          "action": {
                            "function": "test"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With this simple code, where I use the sleep method to emulate a longer script, the app throws the message '...is unable to process your request', and the script executes twice in android **standalone chat app**. In the logging, the onCardClick function executes 2 times, and each time, the script logs the message 'Clicked' to the console.
In a regular browser, despite throws the message '...is unable to process your request', the script only execute one time.
Using the chat app on the mobile browser also doesn't repeat twice.